# How Android 6 determines critical permissions/functions?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I have noticed in Android 6.0 that if you try to disable the permission for PHONE on the stock Phone app, the Settings app informs you that you are disabling a critical function. If this is disabled, *"the basic features of your device may no longer function as intended"*. But, If you try to disable the permission for LOCATION on the phone app, the Settings app does nothing. What is the mechanism that the phone app uses to distinguish a critical function from a non-critical function?

Comment: No magic is going on, the android programmers decided which permission is critical and which is not.

Comment: is there a meta-data attribute that I can add within AndroidManifest of my app to designate a permission as "critical"?

Comment: AFAIK, this is something built into the firmware for specific apps; there is no mechanism for arbitrary apps to trigger this behavior.